AWS CloudWatch Agent - how do you specify a value that depends on EC2 metadata?
I have a scenario where I would like to append a dimension that depends on the value of a specific tag assigned to an instance. For example, I have and instance tagged with Role = X and I would like to append the dimension Role and the value of that dimension is the value of the tag Role.
My guess would be that the syntax is similar to ${aws:InstanceId}. I was able to include the new dimension within the specific metrics like so
"cpu" : {
"append_dimensions" :{
"Role": "${aws:ec2:tag:Role}"
}

but this only resolves to the literal string "${aws:ec2:tag:Role}"
The documentation states here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html
If you want to append dimensions to metrics with arbitrary key-value pairs, use the append_dimensions parameter in the field for that particular type of metric.

If you specify a value that depends on Amazon EC2 metadata and you use proxies, you must make sure that the server can access the endpoint for Amazon EC2. For more information about these endpoints, see Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) in the Amazon Web Services General Reference.

The EC2 instance where the cloudwatch agent is running has a role with ec2:DesribeTags and ec2:DescribeInstances

append_dimensions field should be under metrics field in configuration json file.
But it looks like you put append_dimensions under another metric cpu.

There are two "append_dimensions" fields. One is general for all metrics and supports only ImageId, InstanceId, InstanceType and AutoScalingGroupName, the other one is metric specific. It says so in the documentation If you want to append dimensions to metrics with arbitrary key-value pairs, use the append_dimensions parameter in the field for that particular type of metric. I used cpu as an example
